# partial sum of a power series is almost a power

Tags: nt.number-theory

Using three or more terms of a partial sum within a power series, one gets

$$8+16+32+64=11^2 - 1$$
$$4+8+16+32+64=5^3 - 1$$
$$2+4+8+16+32+64=5^3 + 1$$
$$9+27+36+243=19^2 - 1$$
$$64+128+256+512=31^2 - 1$$

Do you think there is only a finite collection of these almost a power differing by 1?

Comment: I think the fact that Diophantine equations such as $2^x - 2^y + 1 = z^2$ have only finitely many solutions is a known but difficult theorem.  Possibly this one has an elementary solution (though the more general $\sum_{i=m}^n b^i = z^k \pm 1$ with $b,k>1$ may be out of reach).  It seems like an appropriate question for MO, in any case.

Comment: Ok then, but the OP should make the effort of posing the question this way if that's the intent.

Comment: What you call a "power series", J. M., is generally called a "geometric progression", since "power series" means something else, entirely. Although I note that your geometric progressions are somewhat special, as the 1st term is a power of the common ratio.

Comment: J. M. Bergot must agree that his few questions do NOT belong in the BIG league of the latest mathematical research.  He will take his puzzles elsewhere so all your unanswered questions will have time to be answered.

Comment: I believe I misread the comment by Elkies=it seems by accident that my little query maybe suitable for the BIG league.  My previous vaporized query about the last digit of four consecutive primes was in fact the topic of a recent article discussing the infrequency of two consecutive primes both ending in the same last digit.  How can one have any idea what is actually going on in the BIG league when so much research is going on?